# How to work out ''ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part''?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to use a matrix with complex entries to construct a new matrix, but it gives me the warning

> "ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part".

As a result, the new matrix's entries are all real numbers. How to make all the entries keep their imaginary part?

This is the image containing my original code

[image: This is the image containing my original code]

Comment: Could you give us some more details? What is `index_set` and how does it look? Same question for `matrix_1`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have updated my question.

Comment: That kind of indexing shouldn't be causing that problem.  Don't just give us one function; give us a full working example.

Comment: I have attached my original code.

Answer (score 10):

I know where I make this warning happen.

I need to add dtype = "complex_", when I construct a new empty matrix.

For example,

```
mat__ = np.zeros((k*nboxes,k*nboxes),dtype = 'complex_')
```

If we just write

```
mat__ = np.zeros((k*nboxes,k*nboxes))
```

and do some manipulations on that like using a complex matrix to forming a new matrix, then the new matrix will discard the imaginary part.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using numpy to create a new matrix from your Matrix_1 with the array constructor.  That way you can specify that you are using Complex numbers with the `dtype`.  Something like this should do the trick:

`mat_ = np.array(matrix_1[:,ll,ll,:],dtype = "complex_")`

Some testing that I used to make sure:

```
import numpy as np

abc = np.array([[1+1j,2+2j,3+3j],[4+4j,5+5j,6+6j],[7+7j,8+8j,9+9j]],dtype = "complex_") # initial
print(abc)
abc2 = np.array(abc[1:,:1],dtype = "complex_") # post transformation
print(abc2)
```

Comment: Your test case should work without the `dtype` parameters.  The presence of the `1j` value is enough to make both `abc` and `abc2` complex.  Added `np.array` after indexing is not needed.